# Email client that saves attachments with message

Tags: email

Does any know of an email client that saves attachments with messages, like outlook does?

I am currently using Thunderbird and it saves as `eml` file without the attachment included, the attachment must be save separately.

Is there a way to include the attachment with the message when saving in one file and if not what mail client can?

Comment: Have you tried using KMail?  (`sudo apt-get install kmail`) I believe it does this.

Comment: One important comment on that is that you need to be careful with this: hackers sometimes call the attached script something like `"~/home/foo"` and thus are able to overwrite some files in your file system.